# ¿Cómo centrar tarjetas dentro de un display grid?

Tags: html, css

Estoy trabajando en un sitio web y quiero crear un apartado donde se muestren tarjetas dinámicas es decir pueden ser 4, 6, 10, 15 <- Este numero no es fijo para esto estoy metiendo las tarjetas dentro de un div y a este div le coloque el display grid y hago que por fila hayan 4 tarjetas con un width de 23%, el problema es que como le dijo que máximo quiero 4 tarjetas por fila sobran 2 en la siguiente fila pero me los pone hasta la izquierda y quiero lograr que lo centre automáticamente.

¿Alguien me podría ayudar con esto? - Adjunto código css

```
/*Contenedor de todas las tarjetas*/

.ContainerBox{
    margin: auto;
    width: 95%;
    height: auto;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: space-between;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 23%);
    padding-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

/*Tarjeta individual*/

.BoxContainer{
    width: auto;
    height: 413px;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .5s;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 21px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Tambien adjunto imagen de referencia, Del lado izquierdo esta como lo tengo y del lado derecho como lo quiero, Si sabes que esto no se puede hacer con display grid, pero saber como hacerlo te agradecería mucho me lo dijeras :)

[image: Imagen de Referencia]

Comment: Si puedo usar flexbox solo que cuando trate junto todas las tarjetas en una fila y no se como hacer que cada fila solo tenga 4 tarjetas.

Comment: Supongo que el código que las crea las agrupa de 4 en 4, cada bloque de 4 seria una fila flexbox con los items centrados (justify-content: center;). Creo que la solución habría que verla en el código.

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu código html? Al lado del ícono para colocar una imagen en la respuesta, hay un incono para insertar html, y css, de manera que pueda ejecutarse. Sería bueno que colocaras tu código html.-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Puedes usar **flex** para conseguir esta distribución si las tarjetas tienen anchos y margenes determinados:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        body {
            display         : flex;
            flex-wrap       : wrap;
            justify-content : center;
        }
        body div {
            background-color: rgb(220, 220, 255);
            height          : 200px;
            margin          : 1%;
            width           : 23%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Fíjate que en este caso el ancho y la suma de los márgenenes de la tarjeta suma 25%, ya que quieres mostrar 4 tarjetas por fila. Con `flex-wrap: wrap` hacemos que se repartan en diferentes filas, y `justify-content: center` las centra.

Comment: Muchas gracias bro, justo lo que buscaba.

Answer (score 1):

Continuando con el trabajo que ya llevas hecho con *grid* puedes considerar lo siguiente:

- Usar [*`grid-column-start`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column-start) para especificar la posición de un elemento en la cuadrícula y con ello llevar al 5to.div a la segunda columna.

  - Aquí recomiendo leas sobre la [*pseudo clase `nth-child`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)
- Posterior para mantener el centrado horizontal podemos aplicar el uso de [*`justify-self`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout#justifying_items_on_the_inline_axis) pasando `center` como valor a dicha propiedad

**Ejemplo**

```html
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .listado {
        border: 1px solid;
        display: grid;
        grid-gap: 1em;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
       }
      
      .elemento {
        border: 1px solid;
        height: 100px;
        justify-self: center;
        width: 100px;
      }
      
      .elemento:nth-child(5) {
        grid-column-start: 2;
        
      }
    </style>
    
    <div class="listado">
      <div class="elemento"></div>
      <div class="elemento"></div>
      <div class="elemento"></div>
      <div class="elemento"></div>
      <div class="elemento"></div>
      <div class="elemento"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hola bro tu respuesta funciona correctamente solo que el único problema es que como las tarjetas no siempre serán 6 se genera un conflicto como sea muchas gracias.